# Why does the print statement give output as None instead of sorted list?

Tags: python, sorting

```
import random
L = []
for i in range(0, 10):
    L.append(random.randrange(1, 10))
print(L.sort())
```

---

```
Output:None
```

Comment: Because [`list.sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) doesn't return anything (i.e. `None`) - as per the official documentation, the call to the `sort()` method just sorts the list in-place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list.sort` sorts the list in-place and returns `None`. You either want to do:

```
L.sort()
print(L)
```

or use the `sorted` function.

Answer (score 2):

`list.sort` mutates the list instead of returning it.

You can use the `sorted()` function instead:

```
print(sorted(L))
```